# Embed hbar bokeh chart into flask app using function

Tags: python, pandas, flask, bokeh

I'm developing a flask app using bokeh and pandas and I want to convert the below hbar script into a function so I can use it in similar data frames,

this is my code

```
Top_five_all_types_bar_source = ColumnDataSource(Top_five_all_types)
Top_five_all_types_path = Top_five_all_types['con_path'].tolist()
Top_five_all_types_count = Top_five_all_types['Sub_Child_Incident_id']

f_Top_five_all_types= figure(
    y_range=Top_five_all_types_path,
    plot_width =1000,
    plot_height = 300,
    x_axis_label = 'Top Five',


)

f_Top_five_all_types.hbar(
    y='con_path',
    right='Sub_Child_Incident_id',
    left=0,
    height = 0.4,
    source= Top_five_all_types_bar_source
)

hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = """
    <div>Path: @con_path</div>
    <div>Count: @Sub_Child_Incident_id</div>
    <div>Weight: @weight</div>
"""
f_Top_five_all_types.add_tools(hover)

Top_five_all_types_hbar_js, Top_five_all_types_hbar_div = components(f_Top_five_all_types)
```

I tried this function but it gives me an error Top_five_all_types_hbar_js is not defined

```
def HBarChart (source,con_path_col,srs_col,weight, labels, script, div):

    top_five_source = ColumnDataSource(source)
    top_five_path_list = source[con_path_col].tolist()
    top_five_count = source[srs_col]

    f = figure(
    y_range=top_five_path_list,
    plot_width =1000,
    plot_height = 300,
    x_axis_label = labels,
    )

    f.hbar(
    y=con_path_col,
    right=srs_col,
    left=0,
    height = 0.4,
    source= top_five_source
    )

    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips = """
    <div>Path: @con_path_col</div>
    <div>Count: @srs_col</div>
    <div>Weight: @weight</div>
    """
    f.add_tools(hover)

    script, div = components(f)

    return script, div


Top_five_all_types_hbar = HBarChart (
    Top_five_all_types,
    'con_path',
    'Sub_Child_Incident_id',
    'weight',
    'Top Five',
    Top_five_all_types_hbar_js,
    Top_five_all_types_hbar_div
    )
```

The result should be like the below image 
[image: Hbar Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you have come up with accepts `script` and `div` and never uses them. Instead, it creates and returns them. Try changing the signature to

```
def HBarChart (source,con_path_col,srs_col,weight, labels):
    ...
```

And the usage to

```
Top_five_all_types_hbar_js, Top_five_all_types_hbar_div = HBarChart (
    Top_five_all_types,
    'con_path',
    'Sub_Child_Incident_id',
    'weight',
    'Top Five'
    )
```

Comment: Yes it works many thanks but it doesn't show the hover values it shows them  as question marks although the columns names are correct please support

Comment: @IslamFahmy You have to use real column names in the hover tool tooltips and not Python variables. E.g. it has to be `@con_path` instead of `@con_path_col`. If you want to keep them as parameters, just use a format string.